# Extendscript: How can i change text frame attributes in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, javascript

[image: text frame properties]

Hi, I am new to illustrator and do not know about its tools' name. So, I want to change these attributes(underlined in red color shown in the picture) through ExtendScripting. Just let me know their abbreviation of **VA**, **AA**, etc or their functions in Extendscript.

Comment: Hover your mouse over these icons, and the name will be displayed.

Comment: Textframe has no attributes for text the text inside the text frame has a textRange and the range has a style or character attribute attached to it

Comment: Some resources: [AI JS object model chart](https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/objectmodel/objectModel/), [Adobe Illustrator CS6 Type Library JS: Application](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_Application.html#open) (you can go up or down the object tree by following the links on the page),  [TextRange](https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/TextRange/), [CharacterAttributes](https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/CharacterAttributes/), [Working With Text Ranges](https://scriptographer.org/tutorials/typography/working-with-text-ranges/)

Comment: But for example, this would change the leading and tracking of the first textframe in the active document: `var charAttr = app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].textRange.characterAttributes; charAttr.autoLeading = false; charAttr.leading = 70; charAttr.tracking = 200; `

Comment: @Joonas looks like that 2nd link is dead

Comment: @pjpscriv couldn't find equivalent site online, but [these zip files](http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html) should contain the same stuff. Just download the latest html for Illustrator.

Comment: I remembered internet archive is a thing, so [here's that link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200122155529/http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_Application.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build @[Joonas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/2332/joonas)' comment into an answer, these two attributes are called (top to bottom) **Leading** and **Tracking**. As @[Billy Kerr](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/89608/billy-kerr) mentioned you can find these names by hovering over the icons. In ExtendScript their names are - reassuringly - `leading` and `tracking`.

Here's example of them in action taken from the [CS4 Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/pdfs/InDesignCS4_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf) (page 84, 86).

```js
// Create & Get Text Object
var myDocument = app.documents.item(0);
var myPage = myDocument.pages.item(0);
var myTextFrame = myPage.textFrames.add();
myTextFrame.contents = "x";
var myTextObject = myTextFrame.parentStory.characters.item(0);

// Set Leading and Tracking
myTextObject.leading = 12;
myTextObject.tracking = 0;
```

I find the scripting guide can be quite useful. I'm new to ExtendScript and one method I've found is to search for the attribute name in the Scripting Guide, find examples of the attributes being used, and build my code from those examples.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!